# Conversão C para C++

Tags: c, c++

Galera, alguém sabe o que significa este codigo em c++?

```
#include <iostream>

#define MAX_C (10)
using namespace std;

int compar(const void *x, const void *y) {
    int a = *((int *) x);
    int b = *((int *) y);
    return a - b;
}
```

Comment: esse método retorna a diferença de dois valores dentro de ponteiros.

Comment: Fiquei meio confuso, onde entra o "Conversão C para C++" do título na dúvida?

Comment: Acredito que seja porque esse código tem toda cara de C; em C++ daria para fazer usando templates..

Comment: Este código já é C com a excepção do std.

Answer (score 0):

Bom Dia,

Analisando o código, a grande diferente é a utilização da Library IOStream, que nesse código, sinceramente, não está sendo válido. Pois em nenhum momento é chamado algo dessa biblioteca.

Esse #define também não está sendo utilizado nesse código. E se o objetivo é ter uma constante, utilize `const int = MAX_C 10;`

Quanto à função, ela retorna a diferença entre dois ponteiros. Nos quais é feito um cast para int.

Ficaria mais legal utilizar um Template, já que estamos falando de C++.

Abraços

Comment: `const` não é bem isso. `constexpr` seria o adequado.